# I am getting this error when uploading a csv file

Tags: python

I am getting this error while uploading csv file:

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-125-98f27abec4ad> in <module>
----> 1 df2=pd.read_csv(r"C:/Users/Poo/Documents/example/IMDB_data-Copy.csv")
```

Comment: try `\ `  instead of `/`?

Comment: make sure the file path is correct. there is nothing we can do to help you more

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that your OS is Windows, so use `\` instead of `/` as follows:

```
df2=pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\\Poo\Documents\example\IMDB_data-Copy.csv')
```

Keep in mind that this will work because as mentioned by @hiroprotagonist, you are using a raw string (`r''`), if you don't use a raw string, `\` is a special character to scape other characters, so you will have to use `\\`.

Comment: isn't the point of raw strings that they are as is? i.e. no need to escape the backslash?

Comment: @hiroprotagonist,  good catch, you are right. I just missed it. Thanks, I updated my answer.